# Method for check for user input errors. Jquery or PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, validation

I am using a jquery ajax script to submit an html form that will create a user profile. We will need to check for input errors such as spaces in the username, password, or email. Should errors like this be checked client side by using jQuery, or server side by using PHP?

Comment: without server-side checking u have no protections vs all attacks.

Answer (score 3):

Checking in jQuery gives you a faster response to the user to tell them what's wrong, because you don't need to make a round trip to the server to validate; but you should always validate server-side to prevent jQuery validation being bypassed (e.g. calls using curl rather than a web browser, etc), or if client-side js is disabled

Answer (score 2):

Both.

Client side is useful for quick error checking. But, it can by bypassed easily (e.g. turn off Javascript) so you **must** have server-side checking too.

If you had to pick just one, there is actually no choice, use server-side checking.

Answer (score 1):

You should always check for those errors on your server side because what if a user has disabled javascript? The Javascript error checking should only act as an add-on to improve user experience.

Answer (score 1):

They should be checked at both sides.

You use jQuery/JavaScript for a nice and fast user experience. The user will get immediate feedback without having to wait for a server call.

But JavaScript can be disabled or hacked in an easy way (for example, Fiddler can compose Http calls  easily). That's why you also want to check your request on the server.

JavaScript is for the user experience, the server side is for security.

Answer (score 1):

It should be checked on both(client side and server side)
It should be checked on client side to reduce server process and server side if user input the value by firebug, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Always** have server side checks.

Additionally have client side checks where it makes sense.